# can I solve for $\mathbf{x}$ when $\mathbf{x}$, is, itself, a function? $\Vert \mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{I}_{n} \Vert _{2}^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, step-function

Let  $\mathbf{Y}$ be a square matrix, $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $, that can be obtained via a nonlinear operator, $f$, with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, i.e. $\mathbf Y \left(\mathbf{x} \right) =f \left( \mathbf{x} \right)$. And let  $\mathbf{x}$ be a vector,  $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $, containing either $1's$ or $0's$, given by the following Heaviside function:

$$
  \mathbf{x}=h( \mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}} - \alpha)=\begin{cases}
               0~~if~~ \mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}} \lt \alpha \\
               1~~if~~ \mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}} \geq \alpha \\
            \end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha$ is some scalar constant; $\mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}}$ are the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}$, where $\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}$ is simply the matrix  $\mathbf{{Y}}$ from a previous iteration.

Basically, the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is unknown; the "right" value of $\mathbf{x}$ is the one that makes the matrix $\mathbf{{Y}}$ an identity matrix (or close to the identity). Hence, I write the objective function as:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\mathbf{x}^{k+1}}{\text{minimize}}
& &  \Vert \mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{x}^{k+1}) - \mathbf{I}_{n} \Vert _{2}^{2} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \mathbf{x}^{k+1}=h( \mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}} - \alpha)=\begin{cases}
               0~~if~~ \mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}} \lt \alpha \\
               1~~if~~ \mathbf{\tilde{Y}_{i,i}} \geq \alpha \\
            \end{cases} 
&, where~ \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}=\mathbf{Y}^{k}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_{n}$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix; $k$ is the current iteration number.

The question is this:

**can I solve for $\mathbf{x}$ when $\mathbf{x}$, is, itself, a function?** If so,

1. Is there a name for such problems?
2. How can I write this differently?

Comment: It's unclear to how even evaluate $Y$ at a given $x$. As written the definitions are circular. Suppose that $n=1$. Could you give an example of such a $Y$, and how to evaluate it at $x=2$?

Comment: In general you are getting a bit bogged down by the specifics of your problem, I think. In abstract form, you just have: minimize $f(\mathbf{x})$ subject to $g(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$, where both $f$ and $g$ are nonlinear in $\mathbf{x}$. So it is a standard Lagrange multiplier type problem, the only difficulty being that both $f$ and $g$ are probably complicated. Specifically, my $f(\mathbf{x})$ is $\| \mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{I}_n \|_2^2$ and my $g$ is $h(\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{x}))-\alpha)-\mathbf{x}$. (Here in the definition of $g$ I use broadcasting notation as in Matlab.)